# Как правильно создать нужного пользователя для подключения к базе данных Postgresql?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

В качестве теста запустил образ и создал в нем базу данных `shop`. Далее выполняю такой набор команд:

**Создаю нужного мне пользователя**

```
postgres=# create user user1 with superuser password '123456';
CREATE ROLE
```

Даю ему все права на работу с базой:

```
postgres=# GRANT ALL ON DATABASE shop to user1;
GRANT
```

**В итоге получаю такую ошибку:**

```
docker exec -ti otuspg psql -U user1
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  database "user1" does not exist
```

Подскажите, пожалуйта, как правильно создать пользователя для работы с базой данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE database_name TO username;
```

Пользователь создан, права выданы. А дальше у тебя ошибка: `database "user1" does not exist`, что значит, что БД с именем 'user1' не существует. А почему? Потому что это имя пользователя

Comment: Да, но почему такая ошибка? Если ввести команду `docker exec -ti otuspg psql -U  shop`, то получу ошибку, что роли `shop` нет.

Comment: Нужно указать название базы данных под флагом -d: `docker exec -ti otuspg psql -U user1 -d shop`

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо воспользоваться такой командой:

```
docker exec -ti otuspg psql -U user1 -d shop
```

Дело в том, что если не указать параметр `-d`, то база будет выбрана по логину.